# alert messages in response object

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express

I want to show alert messages when a form is submitted without redirecting or navigating to another page.

```
             <form name="myForm" method="POST">
             <input type="submit" name="accept" id="accept" value="Accept">

             <input type="submit" name="accept" id="reject" value="Reject">

             </form>
```

When I click accept or reject,an alert message should pop up without navigating to the other page.

How can I send an alert? What kind of response should I send?

Comment: I use ejs as template engine ,yes